# java.lang.NullPointerException Error in my Database

Tags: java, mysql, database, nullpointerexception, sql-insert

Is there something wrong with my code? I've been for almost an hour in regards to where did I go wrong with my codes, everytime I add an information it always presents an error that it's nullpointerexception, is there a passionate programmers here to help this amateur programmer? I'm just starting out.

```
 if (tf_accnum.equals("") || tf_bankID.equals("") || uname.equals("") ||pword.equals("")) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ALL FIELDS ARE REQUIRED");
   } else  {


       try {

        String sql = "Insert into tbl_memaccount(memaccID,memberID,username,password)values(?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
     ps.setString(1,tf_accnum.getText());
     ps.setString(2,tf_bankID.getText());
     ps.setString(3,uname.getText());
     ps.setString(4,pword.getText());
     ps.execute();
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Successful");


    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: That exception is being generated from your Java code. As you are writing your exception to console, on the exception stack trace what is the line number that exception being originated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a guess that exception is coming from the first line. If any of the your variables `tf_accnum, tf_bankID, uname or pword` is null you will get `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

You can make your empty string check safe as below:

```
if ("".equals(tf_accnum) || "".equals(tf_bankID) || "".equals(uname) || "".equals(pword))
```

Using the above code, even if you get null values for your input variables, it will not get exception and will proceed to `else` code part. But you will be getting exception while setting insert parameters, as you used **{your variable}.getText()**.

A full safe version of your code would be:

```
if (tf_accnum == null || "".equals(tf_accnum)
    || tf_bankID == null || "".equals(tf_bankID)
    || uname == null || "".equals(uname)
    || pword == null || "".equals(pword)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ALL FIELDS ARE REQUIRED");
} else  {
    try {
        String sql = "Insert into tbl_memaccount(memaccID,memberID,username,password)values(?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1,tf_accnum.getText());
        ps.setString(2,tf_bankID.getText());
        ps.setString(3,uname.getText());
        ps.setString(4,pword.getText());
        ps.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Successful");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: the .isEmpty and throw; part of the code is marked in red. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Was it compile error?  It is not clear on your question what are the types of your variables(`tf_accnum`, `tf_bankID`, ...), maybe that is why `isEmpty()` method is missing. I did update the answer to pass compile errors as well, try my updated answer.

Comment: Yep, actually you're right the culprit was my if condition.